# c# wcf service deserialize json array of arrays using json.net

Tags: wcf, air, json.net, deserialization

i'm developing a mobile air application. for comunications i'm using a wcf service.
now my problem is this, i'm trying to deserialize an array of arrays using json.net. the sub arrays are typed.
so, my classes in the mobile side are the following:

```
package Model.VO.PHCDATA
{
    [Bindable]
    [RemoteClass(alias="Model.PCHModel.VODadosPHC")]
    public class VoBi
    {
        private var _BIstamp:String;
        private var _ivaincl:Number;
        private var _vendnm:String;
        private var _vendedor:Number;
        private var _iva:Number;
        private var _lordem:Number;
        private var _tabiva:Number;
        private var _txiva:Number;
        private var _familia:String;            
        ....

    }
}
```

and the other is:

```
package Model.VO.PHCDATA
{
    [Bindable]
    [RemoteClass(alias="Model.PCHModel.VODadosPHC")]

    public class VOBO
    {
        private var _BOstamp:String;
        private var _vendedor:Number;
        private var _vendnm:String;

        ....
    }
}
```

and the corresponding c# classes are the following:

```
    [DataContract(Name = "VoBi")]
    public class VoBi
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "BIstamp", Order = 0)]
        public string BIstamp { get; set; }
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "ivaincl", Order = 1)]
        public decimal ivaincl { get; set; }
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "vendnm", Order = 2)]
        public string vendnm { get; set; }
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "vendedor", Order = 3)]
        public decimal vendedor { get; set; }
                   ....

    }
```

and the other one:

```
 [DataContract(Name = "VOBO")]
    public class VOBO
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "BOstamp", Order = 0)]
        public string BOstamp { get; set; }
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "vendedor", Order = 1)]
        public decimal vendedor { get; set; }
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "vendnm", Order = 2)]
        public string vendnm { get; set; }
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "nmdos", Order = 3)]
        public string nmdos { get; set; }
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "ndos", Order = 4)]
        public decimal ndos { get; set; }

        .....

    }
```

the corresponding json string to be sent to the server is this one:

```
{
    "DADOSBI": [
        {
            "edebito": 0,
            "desconto": 92.121,
            "vendedor": 0,
            "desc2": 222.343,
            "iva": 23,
            "ettdeb": 123.555,
            "lordem": 12,
            "tabiva": 2.1,
           ....
        },
        {
            "edebito": 0,
            "desconto": 92.121,
            "vendedor": 1,
            "desc2": 222.343,
            "iva": 23,
            "ettdeb": 123.555,
            "lordem": 12,
            "tabiva": 2.1,
           ....
        }
    ],
    "DADOSBO": [
        {
            "estab": 123.88,
            "etotaldeb": 123,
            "obs": "",
            "vendedor": 0,
            "statuspda": "qqqqqqqqqqqq",
            "ebo_2tvall": 12,
            "ebo_2tdes1": 12.11,
            ...
        },
        {
            "estab": 123.88,
            "etotaldeb": 123,
            "obs": "",
            "vendedor": 1,
            "statuspda": "qqqqqqqqqqqq",
            "ebo_2tvall": 12,
           ....
        }
    ]
}
```

how do i handle this? do i use json.net CustomCreationConverter to deserialize the data? and obtain the corresponding arrays filled with the classes i've mentioned, or i use another approach?
help would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be better if you could give more information like how do you serialize it? Have you tried `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(yourStream)` since i do not see any typed array in the example (...the sub arrays are typed...), can you update the question with less property examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your top class looks as follows (if you do not have then create one if it is effort less otherwise we need to go a better solution)

```
internal class TopClass
{

    [JsonProperty("DADOSBI")]
    public IList<VoBi> VOBiList { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DADOSBO")]
    public IList<VOBO> VOBOList { get; set; }
}
```

Then simply deserialise using

```
var topClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TopClass>( json);
```

If this is not the answer you are looking for then please update the question with more information

Comment: sorry for the late response. i've been fiddling with some other aspects of the service. but keyr, it's working, the data is being deserialized. thanks for the help